# Multi-column layouts: Pros and cons of float vs display:block?

Tags: css

I want a CSS layout where there is a side-bar on the left-hand side which is 100px. The entire web page must be 400 px wide. What are the pros, cons and general differences between the following different methods?

### Method 1

```
#container {
  width: 400px;
}

#left {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
}

#main {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
}
```

### Method 2

```
#container {
  width: 400px;
}

#left {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
}

#main {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I find it difficult to come up with any pros or cons per se, but method 2 feels more like a hack to me. I'd float #main to the right instead though. With 400px width you won't notice a difference but if you increase the size or want some margin between the columns it'll happen automatically if #main is float: right;

Comment: The reason why I'm asking is I always used to go for method 1, but when I started doing Drupal theme development I found that a lot of people use method 2! I hadn't even thought about that possibility before.

Comment: Ah ok. Well I think method one works better if there are more elements involved and to me it just _feels_ less hacky. From what I've seen of Drupal's code I wouldn't base too much of my own on it.

Comment: For the record, floated elements are implicitly displayed as block elements anyway.

Comment: @utopicam: While my original title wasn't very descriptive, the new one is incorrect. The new title makes it look like I am asking what the difference between `display: block` and `float` is, which is not the point.

Comment: @damd I don't think it does, but I edited it again so it's clear as water.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go with method number 1,

and assuming #main is a div, it already has a property of display:block; by default.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I just wanted to make it clear to people that it's a block-level element without displaying any HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for method #2 is it makes its positioning of the element on the right not rely on the width of the element on the left. Potentially, the element on the left could push the one on the right off the screen or, if too small, could make the page too left justified.